# maximum, minimums and parabolas

Tags: calculus

Help!
Let $f(x,y)$ given by $f(x,y)=ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+l$ in $R^2$.
If $(x_0, y_0)$ is a local maximum point of $f$, show that $(x_0, y_0)$ is an global maximum point.

The suggestion to consider the function $g$ given by $g (t)=f(x_0+ht,y_0+kt)$ and verify that its graph is a parabola.
Even with the suggestion, I could not do it.

Excuse, my English is not very good!

Answer (score 0):

$$g(t)=a(x_0+ht)^2+b(y_0+kt)^2+c(x_0+ht)(y_0+kt)+d(x_0+ht)+e(y_0+kt)+l$$
and this is equal to
$$g(t)=ah^2t^2+bk^2t^2+chkt^2+2ahtx_0+2bhty_0+chty_0+ax_0^2+by_0^2+cx_0y_0+dht+ekt+dx_0+ey_0+l$$
can you go on from here?

Comment: This I did!
I just can not prove why  $f(x_0,y_0)=> f (X)$ on every $X$ in $R^2$.

Comment: Dear, Dr. Sonnhard Graubner really this question is very similar to that as above. I already have the answer.

Thank you so much for trying to help me.